# Keeping track of game state for a Card Trading Game

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am building a card game.  Let's say it's similar to Magic the Gathering, Hearthstone, etc.

The problem I am trying to figure out is how to architect "auras" and how much damage each card takes.

Right now I have a deck and I store card data as follows.  I've made up names for the types of cards that will exist.

```
M.card = {}
-- Minion cards have health and damage
M.card[1].name = "Minion"
M.card[1].hp = 1
M.deck[1].dmg = 1

-- Super Minions have more health and damage
M.card[2].name = "Super Minion"
M.card[2].hp = 4
M.card[2].dmg = 4

-- Spell cards have no health and damage. Instead they affect the health and damage of other cards.
M.card[3].name = "Heal"
M.card[3].details = "This card heals any character for +2 health"
M.card[3].healthboost = 2

M.card[4].name = "Damage Boost"
M.card[4].details = "This card gives + 1 damage to any other card for 1 turn"
M.card[4].dmgboost = 1

-- Super damage boost gives more damage boost to other cards
M.card[5].name = "Super Damage Boost"
M.card[5].details = "This card gives +3 damage to any other card permanently"
M.card[5].dmgboost = 3
```

So when one card attacks another card, I need to keep track of the damage taken by both cards. I don't want to change the base stats of each card so I need to keep track of adjustments.

I could do something like this

```
-- Super Minion takes 3 damage
M.card[2].newHp = 1   
-- or 
M.card[2].adjHp = -3 
-- Not sure which is better.
```

During the battle I need to keep track of which auras are played.   So for example if the Damage boost card is played.  I need to give another card +1 damage for just one turn.

Let's say that I am keep track of each turn number starting from 1.

Should I do something like this

```
M.aura[1] = 4   -- ( aura 1 is card # 4)
M.aura[1].target = 2   -- (this aura is applied to card 2)
M.aura[1].expires = 5  -- (this aura expires on turn 5)

M.aura[2] = 3   -- ( second active aura is heal, card #3 )
M.aura[2].target = 2
M.aura[2].expires = 0   -- this is a one time aura.  So I need to apply it to card #2 and then immediately expire it so it never activates again.
```

Then on every new turn I loop through all the auras and make sure they are still active before a fight begins?

Just wondering architecturally what is the best way to keep track of Damage that characters have taken and spells that are active that are giving characters special abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make the cards instances of immutable reference cards which are never altered during gameplay and compare against the parent of the instance? You could do that with some simple [object orienting](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

Alternatively, if that doesn't suit you, you could give each card a max or base HP field.

```
table.insert(M.card, {
    name = "Wizard",
    hp = 10,
    basehp = 10,
    dmg = 5
})
```

As for time-limited effects on cards, you could track that on the card itself.

```
M.card[1].effects = { { dmgboost = 2, expires = 3 } }
```

Give the base card a function such that it calculates the card's stats based off of effects.

```
function Card:damage()
    local d = self.dmg
    for _, v in ipairs(self.effects) do
        if v.dmgboost then d = d + v.dmgboost end
    end
    return d
end

function Card:processEffects()
   for i = #self.effects, 1, -1 do
       if turn >= self.effects[i].expires then
           table.remove(self.effects, i)
       end
   end
end
```

These are only a few examples out of many ways that you could handle this. However, I'm sure this will be enough to give you some ideas for now.

Comment: I like this approach.  But how do I handle effects that other cards give, where those effects die when the other card is destroyed. Let's say that card 1 gives +1 damage to all other friendly cards.  I don't want to add a +1 damage effect to all the cards and have the expiration tied to the death of the original card.  Instead it probably makes more sense to have the effect tied to the card that gives the effect so when the card dies the effect is automatically removed from all cards.  But how would you program this?

Comment: @fun_programming You could give the effect a field which points to the card that gave them the effect, such as `dependsOn`, then when you're processing the effects to remove or otherwise handle them, check if the dependent card is still in play, and if not, remove the effect.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the existence of a card temporarily affect the qualities of another card, use an observer or callback pattern. When you "draw" (out of the deck or hand) the special card which adds +1 damage to all other friendly cards, presumably you have a function `findAllOtherFriendlyCards(yourSpecialCard, allCards)` which does that. Then in this function, for each friendly card you find, you "register" the friendly card with the special card by calling `specialCard:registerDiscard(yourFriendlyCard)`. Then when the special card gets discarded, which presumably happens by calling `specialCard:discard()`, this method looks at all registered cards and re-adjusts the attribute that the special card affected.

In fact, you don't need a separate register method, you could just have a `specialCard:startEffect(friendlyCard)`: this method adjusts some attributes on friendlyCard and keeps it in a list; and you have a `specialCard:endEffect(friendlyCard)` which does the opposite, i.e. adjusts the attributes in the opposite direction (+1 if it -1'd at start, etc) and removes the card from its list of affected cards.

If friendly cards can be discarded before the special cards get discarded, you use a similar technique: the friendly card must keep track of every special card that adjusted it and notify the special card when it gets discarded, so the special card can remove it from its list.